# How to bind methods to combobox in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have this simple combobox in my .fxml

```
<ComboBox fx:id="comboShapes" prefWidth="150.0" value="Random">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Random" />
            <String fx:value="Small Exploder" />
            <String fx:value="Gospler Glider Run" />
            <String fx:id="comboGlider" fx:value="Glider" />
         </FXCollections>
   </items>
</ComboBox>
```

And I'm wondering how I can bind set methods to the different choicebox Strings in Controller?

Comment: Are you trying to set the choicebox based on an action taken?

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I'm i.e trying to bind method initSmallExploder() to the Small Exploder string in the combobox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In your controller define an [`onAction(ActionEvent event)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#setOnAction-javafx.event.EventHandler-) action handler for your combo box.
2. Link the fxml to your controller action handler via `onAction="#choiceMade"` (where choiceMade is the arbitrary name I chose for the action handler method).
3. In your action handler perform a switch on the combo box value to invoke the appropriate method handler for the selected value.

[image: pic]

*application/ComboAction.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="226.0" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.ComboActionController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="choiceLabel" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="comboShapes" onAction="#choiceMade" prefWidth="150.0" value="Random">
         <items>
            <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
               <String fx:value="Random" />
               <String fx:value="Small Exploder" />
               <String fx:value="Gospler Glider Run" />
               <String fx:value="Glider" />
            </FXCollections>
         </items>
      </ComboBox>
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</VBox>
```

*application/ComboActionApp.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboActionApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ComboAction.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*application/ComboActionController.java*

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class ComboActionController {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> comboShapes;

    @FXML
    private Label choiceLabel;

    @FXML
    void choiceMade(ActionEvent event) {
        String choice = comboShapes.getValue();

        choiceLabel.setText(
                "Chosen: " + choice
        );

        switch (choice) {
            case "Random":
                randomChosen();
                break;

            case "Small Exploder":
                smallExploderChosen();
                break;

            case "Gospler Glider Run":
                gliderChosen();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void gliderChosen() {
        // todo implement action handler.
    }

    private void smallExploderChosen() {
        // todo implement action handler.
    }

    private void randomChosen() {
        // todo implement action handler.
    }

}
```